# Using hashmap in Java Selenium for verifying Months

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, hashmap, logic

My automation framework is Perfecto cloud based using Selenium API in Java. 
In my test scenario I need to open Calendar in Month view and then swipe it(Right to Left) and then verify the next month is displayed or not. 
I read on few posts and found that HaspMap can be used for this. Can anybody guide me on how to use hashmap for such scenario. Some code snippet will really help.

Test Steps:

1. Launch Calendar in Month View
2. Capture the current month (eg - March) and save in String curMonth
3. Now swipe(right to left) for Month to Change
4. Capture the value of the Month displayed on screen (Now comes April) and save in String nextMonth
5. Verify the value nextMonth is actually the value next to curMonth

Below code sample which I am trying to use. read the comments

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> Table = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    Table.put("JAN", 1);    
    Table.put("FEB", 2);    
    Table.put("MAR", 3);    
    Table.put("APR", 4);    
    Table.put("MAY", 5);    
    Table.put("JUN", 6);    

    String testdata="MAR";
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    Integer curMon = Table.get(testdata);
    System.out.println(curMon);
    //Here output will be 3 which it will fetch from the hashmap table

    //Now I am adding 1 from the return value which is 3. So 3+1=4 
    Integer newMonthValue=curMon+1;

    //Now how to associate the integer value which is 4 stored in newMonthValue and map it to April from the Map
```

Comment: With my scenario I assume after reading few post that HaspMap should be used, hence posted this.

Comment: OK, but adding a link to a few would help understand the scenario. A `HashMap<Key, Value>` maps a value to a key. What do you see as the key and value for these dates and why can't you just directly compare the two (previous and current) dates?

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain month name by value you can simply call this utility method:

```
private static String getMonthByValue(HashMap<String, Integer> table, Integer newMonthValue) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry : table.entrySet()) {
        if (mapEntry.getValue().equals(newMonthValue)) {
            return mapEntry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or more concise version with `Java 8` `Stream API` features:

```
private static String getMonthByValue(HashMap<String, Integer> table, Integer newMonthValue) {
    return table.entrySet()
       .parallelStream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().equals(newMonthValue))
       .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
       .findAny()
       .orElse(null);
}
```

usage:

```
String newMonthName = getMonthByValue(Table, newMonthValue);//returns "APR" in your case
```